# Calculation of AM,PM and After Hours on a query set

Tags: sql

I have the following record in my table:
WardInDateTime , WardOutDateTime
2013-01-31 11:31:00.000 ,2013-02-01 01:30:00.000

I need to write code to split the record up into AM Hours used, PM Hours Used and After Hours Used.
AM Hours 07:00 to 13:00
PM Hours 13:00-19:00
Everything that does not fall into this category  can be marked as after hours
So my result set would need to look something like:
Date   ,    AMHours  ,  PMHours , AFTER HOURS
2013-01-31   29 mins , 360 mins ,  300 mins
2013-02-01   0 mins ,    0 mins , 90 mins

Now I have joined the query with a date table to split the query up into different days
i.e Inner join Time on (T.Date between wardIndate and wardOutDate) to split the records, but I am 
stuck from there. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with the query similar to following. I have just calculated AMHours. Similarly other hours can be calculated.

```
WITH CutOff 
AS
(
SELECT CONVERT(NVARCHAR,WardInDateTime,110) AS FormattedDate
,WardInDateTime
,WardOutDateTime
,DATEADD(hh, 13, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, WardInDateTime)))  AMCutOff
,PMCutOff = DATEADD(hh, 19, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, WardInDateTime)))
,OtherCutOff = DATEADD(hh, 07, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, WardInDateTime)))
FROM Ward
)
SELECT FormattedDate AS Date, CASE WHEN WardInDateTime < AMCutOff AND WardOutDateTime < AMCutOff
            THEN DATEDIFF(MI,WardInDateTime,WardOutDateTime)
            WHEN WardInDateTime < AMCutOff
            THEN DATEDIFF(MI,WardInDateTime,AMCutOff)
            ELSE 0 END AS AMHours
FROM CutOff 
;
```